# Pandas can't join DataFrames after set_index with exception `IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2`

Tags: python, pandas

When I run the code below the join operation throws `IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2`. If I change the index's name *before* I write the file it works, but in the context where I'm trying to use this the file writing operation is hard to change.

To be fair, my pandas version is a bit old: 0.12.0. I can't find evidence that this is a pandas bug that has been fixed, but I could easily be wrong.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

FILEPATH = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/foo.csv")

def write_df(filepath):
    # http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/dsintro.html#from-dict-of-series-or-dicts
    d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
         'two' : pd.Series([5., 6., 7., 8.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    #df.index.name = "letter" # This fixes it
    df.to_csv(filepath)

def read_df(filepath):
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    # inplace = False does not help here
    df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'letter'}, inplace=True)
    df.set_index("letter", inplace=True)
    return df

write_df(FILEPATH)
dfs = [read_df(FILEPATH), read_df(FILEPATH)]
dfs[0].join(dfs[1], lsuffix="_0", rsuffix="_1")
```

Comment: Your code runs without error using Pandas 0.16.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the issue was it is fixed in Pandas 0.16.2. H/T unutbu